# Keyboard shortcut for printing in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, printing

Is there a keyboard shortcut that you can use to print selected files in Windows File Explorer? If not, is there any way to assign one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file association listed a print verb then pressing Shift+F10, P (as for text files) will print it. It is **program specific**.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement printing from Explorer is to add a context menu item for **each** document type to be printed. The application that handles one document type might not handle another, so an application must be specified for each.

For example, MS *Paint* can display and print a *.png* image, but not a LibreOffice *Writer* *.odt* document.

Here is how to create a *Print* context menu item for a *.txt* file in Windows 10. **N.B.** Be *very* careful using Regedit. It is a good idea to make a disk image before making major changes.

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `rege` and select *Regedit*.
2. Allow it to run in the UAC dialog.
3. Find the application, in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications`, that would normally open that file type. Note that in the screenshot below, on this PC, *.txt* files are opened by *Notepad++*, not by *Notepad*, so changes are made  to the *Notepad++* key!
4. Right-click on `shell` and create a new key, `print`.
5. Right-click on `print` and create a new key, `command`.
6. Double-click on the REG_SZ string `(Default)` and change its value to the location of the app to print with the correct command-line arguments, here,

   `"C:\Windows\System32\NOTEPAD.EXE" /p "%1"`.

[image: Use Regedit to make Print context menu item]

BTW, rather than starting the larger *Notepad++* app to print, I chose to use MS *Notepad* for that purpose. Note also that quotes may be needed around the application path and the file path argument (%1), but *not* around the command-line argument, *%p*, to print.

Ahhh... but where is the **keyboard shortcut** you requested? Here:

- In Explorer, with the desired file selected, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> to see the context menu.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to select *Print*, if the *P* in print has an underscore (if not, use the underscored letter).

Comment: can you update shortcut because at windosw 11 context menu there is no print option/ print optin after press G